# Restore Purchase for iAP shows alert on app startup

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have 2 problems when I added the restore method for iAP...

Problem 1: Everytime I open my app a iTunes alert comes up and ask if I wanna login  to the iTunes Store. This happens since I add the following restore  method:

```
- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Now, even when I remove the restore method the alert keeps on coming  at startup. It seems that Apple already connects with iTunes at the  startup of the app. I wanna make this only when a user hits the purchase  or restore button. I read several things on StackOverflow that you have  to add something in your AppDelegate so that the app is not connecting  automatically but with still no luck.

Problem 2: When testing the iAP on my phone and hit the restore button the item can  be restored, even if I didn't purchased it before. Is this normal when  testing the restore function with a test account? You should say that  Apple have to show alert that the item has never been purchased and  cannot be restored?

Can someone please guide me step-by-step with this to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self unlockFeature];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off don't post duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474139/restore-purchase-method-for-iap-shows-alert-on-app-startup second, what is in your `viewDidLoad` `viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear` methods.

Comment: Ah sorry, my viewDidLoad:- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
}

Comment: @sbarow, the link you provided has been removed by the moderators. FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something similar to your first problem whilst I was adding IAP's to an app. It turned out that whilst I had been going through testing it and changing things I had got a backlog of pending transactions, so every time I opened the app it was trying to finish those off. If you sign in, let it do anything it needs, close, reopen and repeat I managed to catch up and it stopped asking me to sign in every time. It might be worth giving that a shot. (I'm trying to dig out the question that I got this answer from).

It is restoring the IAP because you are calling [self unlockFeature] when the restore transaction queue finish's even if it hasn't restored anything:

```
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self unlockFeature];
}
```

You should remove the unlockFeature call and sort the transaction handling in the

```
-paymentqueue:updatedtransactions:
```

Add this to the switch:

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        [self unlockFeature];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
        finishTransaction:transaction];
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the alert also stops showing up suddenly... I'm now gonna try to create a new test user and hope it works.

Comment: I have updated my answer to why you might be restoring the feature on a user that hasn't already made the purchase.

Comment: your answer also solved my first problem :) I did not call finishTransactions when updatedTransactions is called after a restoreCompletedTransactions request. This was generating numerous transactions in the queue. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Glad I could help :) It's often the smallest things that go unnoticed!

Comment: Heheh yes indeed :) I was looking at it too long I guess and trying to many different things with no succes. Thnx again :)